# Event generation on selection of Alphabetical sections in table table view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

I am getting some contacts from a web service, and I need to show them in a tableview in alphabetical along with an alphabetical section. This part is done.

Screenshot:

[image]

The problem is, for some logic implementation, I actually need to identify the alphabet the user has selected from the alphabet section. I cannot find any delegate methods of tableView that can identify when an alphabet has been selected in the alphabet section.

Methods I have implemented:

```
1)  func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {}
2)  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {} and other mandatory tableview services.
```

Is there a delegate method, or a way to generate an event when one of the alphabets is selected?

Comment: As @Andreas Oetjen said you can get index using `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    if let index = sections.firstIndex(where: { $0 == title }) {
        return index
    }
    return 0
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct event you could handle when the user taps on a section index title, but what you could implement is

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, 
                           at index: Int) -> Int
```

This method is called on the data source  and translates a section index title to a section in the table view. This is typically called when the user taps on an entry in the index.